# Measurability of a function squeezed by sequence of measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a complete measure space. Show that for sequences $(f_n), (g_n)$ of measurable functions $f_n,g_n:X\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f: X\to\mathbb{R}$ with

1. $f_n\leq f_{n+1}\leq f\leq g_{n+1}\leq g_n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty} \|g_n-f_n\|_1=0$

We have that $f$ is measurable.

I have tried the following.
I want to prove by definition that $f$ is measurable. For that we have to show (by definition) that for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is measurable.

To achive this I thought that when I can show that $f_n\to f$ (or $g_n\to f$) with regards to $\|\cdot\|_1$, then I can express

$f^{-1}(a,\infty)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty f^{-1}_n(a,\infty)$ or

$f^{-1}(a,\infty)=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty g^{-1}_n(a,\infty)$

which would yield the measurability of $f$, as $f_n, g_n$ are measurable and so is the intersection or union.

I am confidend that $f_n\to f$ and $g_n\to f$, by the given properties, but so far I was not able to prove it.
Also I do not see how the completness is going to be necessary so far.

Can you help me out? Is there a better approach, or would this scetch work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only prove that $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $g_n \to f$ a.e. $f$ need not be Borel measurable but you can show that it is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, I thought so after scimming through the lecture notes, that we have this. This would make place to use the completness by observing the null set where $f_n, g_n$ do not converge. Can you however get me started on how to prove that the sequences converge almost everywhere? Writing out the definitions did not help me so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F=\lim f_n$ and $G=\lim g_n$. These limits exist by montonicity.

Note that $(0 \leq )g_n-f_n $ decreases to $F-G$. Also, $g_n-f_n$ is integrable (at least for large $n$). This implies, by Monotone Convergence Theorem , that $F=G$ a.e. It is now clear that $f_n \to f$ and $g_n \to g$ a.e.

Comment: How does monotonicity imply the existence of these limits? Do we not need boundedness too?

Comment: In Measure Theory you work in the extended real line. Boundened is not necessary. @Cornman

Comment: Oh right. I forgot about that we allow $\pm\infty$. Probably because the function maps into the reals.